# Combining outputs into single hash/dictionary JQ

Tags: json, dictionary, jq

So I've got a json object that looks like this :

```
[{
    "size": "77824",
    "module": "rfcomm",
    "depcount": "4",
    "deps": []
}, {
    "size": "98304",
    "module": "scsi_transport_iscsi",
    "depcount": "4",
    "deps": []
}, {
    "size": "16384",
    "module": "xt_conntrack",
    "depcount": "1",
    "deps": ["nouveau", "i915"]
}]
```

And I can use the following jq rule `.[] | { (.module) : (.deps | join(",")) }` into a series of objects that look like this

```
{
  "rfcomm": ""
}
{
  "scsi_transport_iscsi": ""
}
{
  "xt_conntrack": "nouveau,i915"
}
```

I've added a [jq play example](https://jqplay.org/s/8cXYKv2qlU) of what I see.

What I'd like it to get output that combines those objects. So something like :

```
{
  "rfcomm": "",
  "scsi_transport_iscsi": "",
  "xt_conntrack": "nouveau,i915"
}
```

I'm a bit of a jq novice so I'm sure there's a way to do it I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility:

```
[.[] | { (.module) : (.deps | join(",")) }] | add
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility (sort of functional approach):

```
reduce .[] as $elem ({}; . + { ($elem.module): $elem.deps | join(",") })
```

The general syntax is:

```
reduce inputs as $elem (INIT; REDUCER)
```

- `INIT` initial value of the output variable could be e.g. `[]` or `{}`
- `REDUCER` code that is executed on each element `. +` makes sure it gets appended to the intermediate result (the output)