# crunch series of hashes into single hash

Tags: json, jq

I am processing a large json structure which is in foo.json

at the completion of this filter
`jq '.[] | select(.entity_id|test("sensor.current.")) | { (.entity_id) : .state}   ' foo.json`
having reduced the list of components with a select() I get:

```
{
  "sensor.current_consumption": "1.4"
}
{
  "sensor.current_power": "194.6"
}
{
  "sensor.current_mains_voltage": "239.9"
}
```

What I want is
`{ "sensor.current_consumption": "1.4", "sensor.current_power": "194.6", "sensor.current_mains_voltage": "239.9" }`

I have tried to read up on jq's  map() and add() but cannot make much sense. Similar questions have been asked before and looking at answers e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52547428/combining-outputs-into-single-hash-dictionary-jq) I tried

```
jq '.[] | select(.entity_id|test("sensor.current.")) | map({ (.entity_id) : .state}) | add   ' foo.json
jq: error (at foo.json:0): Cannot index string with string "entity_id"
```

and

```
jq '.[] | select(.entity_id|test("sensor.current.")) | map({ (.entity_id) : .state}) | add   ' foo.json
rrent.")) | map({ (.entity_id) : .state}) | add   ' foo.foo
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: Your output does not match your jq program: all keys must start with `"sensor.current."`, but none of your keys does (they start with `"sensor.current_"`)

Comment: @knittl The output is perferctly fine. All keys from the sample output pass the `test` using (regex) `"sensor.current."`.

Comment: @pmf: oh, you're absolutely correct. `.` is a regex meta character; I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me in eating large Json blocks

```
jq 'map(select(.entity_id|startswith("sensor.current")) | { (.entity_id) : .state})| add' foo.json
```

and many thanks to @knittl and @pmf

Answer (score 1):

If your input is large, you may want to use `reduce` to iteratively build up your output object:

```bash
… | reduce (.[] | select(.entity_id | test("sensor.current."))) as $item ({};
      .[$item.entity_id] = $item.state
    )
```

Note that `test` works with regular expressions, so the `.` in `"sensor.current."` means any character. You might want to use `contains` or `startswith` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate the elements of the array with `.[]` but [`map`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#map-map_values) them to a new array, then `add` them to a single object:

```
map(select(.entity_id|startswith("sensor.current.")) | { (.entity_id) : .state})
| add
```

Alternatively, [`reduce`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#reduce) to your final object:

```
reduce (.[] | select(.entity_id|startswith("sensor.current.")))
as $x ({}; .[$x.entity_id] = $x.state)
```

The third option is using [`from_entries`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries-from_entries-with_entries) to construct an object from an array of key-value-pairs:

```
map(select(.entity_id|startswith("sensor.current.")) | { key: .entity_id, value: .state})
| from_entries
```

Comment: thank you @knittl : I went with your second solution having picked up @pmf 's point about pattern matching so 'jq 'map(select(.entity_id|startswith("sensor.current")) | { (.entity_id) : .state})| add' ` So thanks to both and for introducing me to startswith